# SEToolKit - Unable to locate package set

Tags: google-cloud-shell

i wrote

```
git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/ setoolkit/
cd setoolkit
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py
```

then i wrote

`cd SEToolkit` then `ls` i've found zero files on it.

i tried to install setoolkit again so write `sudo apt install set` but unfortunately it outputted:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package set
```

what should i do to use to this tool's files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `setoolkit` as a root in Cloud Shell. I followed this [document](https://pablokribo.wordpress.com/2016/06/20/install-setoolkit-on-ubuntu-14-04/) even this is old it still working. Inside the docs here are the steps :

1. `sudo apt-get install git`
2. `sudo -sH`
3. `cd /opt`
4. `git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit/ setoolkit/`
5. `cd /opt/set`
6. `python setup.py install`

Then, to start run:

7. `setoolkit`

Comment: @RawanEltheni Let me know if you can't still use it then provide more details.